# External Values into Javascript Operator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put an external value into an Javascript var function.
The code is shown as below:

```
var zxc = {

     // Application Constructor
     initialize: function() {

     this.bindEvents();
     console.log("Starting NFC Reader app");
     },
     // Bind Event Listeners
     bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady(), false);
     },

     // deviceready Event Handler
     onDeviceReady: function() {
     //app.receivedEvent('deviceready');


         nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
         zxc.onNfc, // tag successfully scanned
         function (status) { // listener successfully initialized

         },
         function (error) { // listener fails to initialize

         }
         );
     },


     onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
     console.log("invoked function");
     var record1 = ndef.mimeMediaRecord('text/plain', '222');
       console.log(record1);
     nfc.write(
            [record1],
            function () {
               console.log("Wrote Data to Tag");
            },
            function (reason) {
             console.log("ERROR");
            }
      );


    }
 };


 zxc.initialize();
```

I'm trying to make this line the value(222) dynamic,

```
var record1 = ndef.mimeMediaRecord('text/plain', '222');
```

i.e, where I can pass in external values into zxc.initalize().
But the whole function is so complicated and dependent on each other,  I would really love to have some guidance to how to solve this problem.
I'm currently using chariotstudios nfc cordova plugin. 
Thank you!

Note: If you wish to know what is addTagDiscoveredListener (screenshot taken from https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc),

[image: Taken from https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc]

Comment: `var` not a function - this is `operator`

Comment: @Grundy thanks! i made the changes!

Comment: so, what you want? pass something value to `initialize` method and use it in `onNfc`?

Comment: @Grundy, yes , would want to pass it to onNfc!

Comment: An example: https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api/tree/master/ExternalNFCWebKiosk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add parameter to `initialize` and just save it like

```
initialize: function(myparam) {
    this.myparam = myparam;
    ....
}
```

for using this field you can do something like this

```
onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
    console.log("invoked function");
    var record1 = ndef.mimeMediaRecord('text/plain', zxc.myparam);
    ...
}
```